# How to write bootstrap media queries

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am not getting how to write bootstrap media query for 768*1024 and larger devices. I know I can use @media then screen size{}, but I have write css for each and every tag button and rest elements? Is there any shortcut way? If I have to write then how can I write. Please someone provide me, sample code for bootstrap @media query to make my app responsive in tablet like devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you need custom media queries, bootstrap already has them built in for xs, sm, md, lg, with breakpoints at <767px, 768-991px, 992-1200, >1201px respectively.

Comment: Yes shawn but i cant able to click on the buttons and links at 768*1024 in firefox browser i tried. What may be the reason for this? I dont like designing.

Comment: I think you better post some code for us to look at.

Comment: Thanks shawn changed my code. I tried putting only bootstrap template i mean my app skeleton without my code and it worked so i changed my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...depending on the size of the device there are many classes that help you achieve what you want in specific resolutions.

First of all in the customizer of bootstrap before downloading you can set your own breakpoints, then depending on the class you can use -xs- -sm- -md- -lg- along with the class you want to use it just for the specific resolutions.

For example:

using class 'visible-xs-block' means that this class that applies the display:block style, will only appear in XS devices - this depends of if you have custom breakpoints or using the default which is for devices up to 767px

edit: if you were using the class 'visible-lg-block' instead would mean that the class would only be applied for large devices (≥1200px).

Of course you can mix and match which classes you want, you can use both of these classes on the same element like:

```
<div class="visible-xs-block visible-lg-block">
```

..that would make the element visible only on xs and lg devices.

You can learn the functions/etc by using the help online;

http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Thanks scooterlord almost clear but need some example to write media css upvote for the info. Thanks for ur info.

Comment: Media queries is a css thing - not a bootstrap thing. Besides that, read the documentation. do you want us to copy/paste the docs for you?

Comment: Ok scooterlord cool. See i know bootstrap is responsive also i have written class for sm xs and lg but i cant click when it loads in 768*1024 else my app works fine in 368, 340 and rest screens. I taught there must Some way out to make it work writting css for 768 screen.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention used md too. The view is perfect for all types of screen but i cant able to click on buttons. Right now i am using cell so tomo i will check my code once again.

Comment: I did some changes in my code.. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is already responsive for tablets and phones as long as you use their grid system (try viewing the main Bootstrap site in such a device for examples). You'd only need media queries if you wanted to override or extend its default responsive behaviour.

Comment: Thanks upvote for your info but still i am confused about the usage of media queries.

Answer (score 1):

Sudarashan I think if I read your further comments right, that you have an issue with specifically the 768px *width* screen size upto 1024px.

This code (taken from the [Bootstrap site](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries)) shows the standard breakpoints at which bootstrap operates.

---

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, less than 768px) */
/* No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap */

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-lg-min) { ... }
```

---

Your initial question mentions that you are looking to respond between **768px** and **1024px**. This would start responding within the parameters of *sm (small)* **768px**

```
/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-sm-min) { ... }
```

BUT, would then run into the *md (medium)* parameter **992px** (and above) all the way up to the desired **1024px** that you are aiming for.

```
/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) { ... }
```

### The solution

In this case you might be as well writing a new media query confined to the parameters you require here. From my understanding that would be as follows:

```
/* Custom sizes (768px to 1024px) */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {... }
```

This should provide the required breakpoint that fits your app I believe.

Comment: Thanks for your response. My app is working now i did some changes to my code. Its responding to clicks and links.